# SQL dynamic query with empty check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SET @sql = 'Declare  ChildTableMigrator  CURSOR FOR  select ['+@FieldName+'] , ['+@FieldName+'Alias] from ['  + @SourceTable + '].[dbo].[Port] where ['  + @SourceTable + '].[dbo].[Port].[' + @FieldName +  '] IS NOT NULL AND ['  + @SourceTable + '].[dbo].[Port].[' + @FieldName +  '] !='''

PRINT @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Hi,

How to check `NULL` and `EMPTY` with a `sql` dynamic query ?  , as per `EMPTY` check

```
@FieldName +  '] !='''
```

it thorws the error

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

How to overcome this ?

Comment: You've got the `print` statement right there - did you not *look* at the printed query?

Comment: Don't use `['+@FieldName+']` but use `'+ quotename(@FieldName) + '`. When I use `set @FieldName = 'omg]thisfails'` as field name your solution crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
 @FieldName + '] !='''
```

with

```
 @FieldName + '] !='''''.
```

Quotation marks need to be escaped when used inside a string. In your original statement, you escaped only one quotation mark resulting in a string with only one quotation mark.

But you could do even better by using parametrized sql

```
 @FieldName + '] !=@EmptyField
 exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@EmptyField VARCHAR(32)', ''
```

Answer (score 1):

use  if() judge .for example

```
 set @sql="Declare  ChildTableMigrator  CURSOR FOR  select "
if(@FieldName!=null)
   begin
      set @sql=@sql+"['"+@FieldName+"']";
   end
 .....

PRINT @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```